# Where to find espn api key?

Tags: espn

I have been looking at the [ESPN API](http://espn.go.com/apis/devcenter/). However, I have not been able to find documentation on how to get an API KEY. There is nothing in the `Getting Started` section about getting an API key. Also, I logged into ESPN and went to my Account Information, but I do not see anything there about an API key.

Comment: From the top page of ESPN dev center: "[Please read this important announcement](http://espn.go.com/static/apis/devcenter/blog/read/publicretirement.html) about the issuance of new public developer keys and a change in the ESPN API service." Unless they also have some other kind of keys (non-public keys?) I haven't figured out...

Comment: Okay, so it isn't possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they have blocked the ability to register for an API key. 
However, you can get NHL statistics for example by scrapping it from their official site using GitHub solutions such as this one:
https://github.com/sintaxi/nhl-api

If there are other open ones I am on the quest as well will be following this!